Using the definition of a derivative, show that $f(z) = |z|$ is nowhere differentiable
I have been able to use the derivative to get to the point where $\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} f(z) = |z|$ = $\frac{\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2}-\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}{\Delta z}$
I take the multiply by $1$, using $\frac{\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2}+\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}{\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2}+\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$.
Now, when I consider the limit along the $x$-axis, $\Delta y =0$ and so $\Delta z = \Delta x$.
So, my fraction will simplify to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}$ since we know that $y = 0$.
The worked solutions provided to me show that denominator to be $x^2$ without the root. Is this a typo or have I made a mistake.
Thank you in advance.

It is not true that this function is nowhere differentiable.

@Hans it is slightly misleading, I thought it is real absolute value as well. But it is complex norm, with complex derivative, and it is true.
